# Unsecured network neighborhood printer keeps interrupting my connection

Tags: wireless-networking

An unsecured "HP-Print-53-Photosmart 5520" printer somewhere near my house has been interrupting my high-speed Charter internet lately. (I didn't even know printers had internet.) This gets very frustrating especially when in the middle of serious matters, like online poker which I do play.

My connection gets messed up by it because my laptop sees it and, of course, goes to automatically connect to it. When I go to knock it off the Manage Wireless Connection list it's not even there.

Also, how can I block my neighbors wifi? No matter how many times I uncheck the "Connect automatically" box you other people speak of it helplessly does nothing. Reopen the "Internet access" box again and it is checked.

But mainly, is there anyway I can **block** this printer device from my network connections?

Comment: Heh, and then it might be because this is actually a superuser.stackexchange question as not a speck of security is involved...

Comment: I suggest you connect to the rogue printer and print a few copies of a friendly message warning that "this printer is unsecured".

Answer (score 1):

If I assume correctly, this is a case of your laptop attempting to connect to "superior" WiFi access points? Reminds of an [xkcd panel](http://xkcd.com/416/).

Stopping this would depend on your operating system.

For Windows, you could try a restricted white-list of acceptable access points:

- http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/03/how-to-use-group-policy-to-blackwhite-list-wireless-networks-in-vista-windows-7/

For Mac, information on this is harder to find, but you could try:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39922/how-to-disable-automatic-wifi-connection

Alternately, there could simply be too many competing access points in your vicinity:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3804892?start=0&tstart=0

---

Unfortunately you are experiencing the dilemma of a [shared commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons).

WiFi devices are supposed to play nice, but they don't always do so. The only device whose behavior you can control is your own - which can be too "user friendly" to tailor to your specific needs. Every color so long as it's black.

Comment: Thanks, I think that whitelist suggestion sounds alright. I'll give it a whirl and hope that that's how to fix it.

Comment: Uh oh. It looks like I don't have the "Group Policy Editor" referred to in the top link. I've tried downloading a fan-made version of it and did all the things I had to do to make it work for my Windows 7 Home Premium, but no luck. I just want to block this stupid connection.

Comment: You guys, enters a set of commands into command prompt. Something like "netsh wlan remove filter" or what have you, and still even now it disconnects ever now and then. Those commands only seem to have hid it from the "Currently connected to" box.